# Automatic Mapping of LAN using Traceroute?

Tags: local-area-network, networking

range. Then, it should compare the data to see that all packets are going through a specific IP, and denote that as a switch and build a tree. This way, I need a software that can automatically generate a map of the network topology.

Comment: Did you clip the start of your question off?!

Comment: You're a little confused. If you traceoute between two machines, a switch (a L2 device) will not show up, even if it has a management interface with an IP on the same subnet as your two machines. Routers will show up, because they are L3 devices. If you've got all-Cisco, and have CDP turned on, then maybe you can try to map your layer 2 devices.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are a number of software programs that do this very thing. Google the phrase: network mapping software

Comment: Why did the Community user bump this thread after 4 months? (bumped to top of homepage queue on Dec 31, 2010)

Comment: TracerT for the win... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got the topology function in NMap working. I'm posting this as an answer in case someone else comes looking for the same question (also coz I can't find the comment button). Just google nmap, or go to insecure.org.

@Izzy, ya, it does seem that way. I dunno why, Server Fault was acting really wierd as I was trying to create a new account on SF while ensuring that it linked automatically to my much used accounts on Stack Overflow and SuperUser.

@mfinni, yes, I am not actually a sysadmin and have always been confused by the difference between the various network devices. I only said switch coz when I ran an NMap scan on my school network, it showed all the traffic to other computers passing through one IP, and labelled it through service/version detection as a Cisco switch. Well actually now that I think about it, while it labelled the device as a switch, the OS mentioned was Cisco Router.

@joeqwerty, I knew there had got to be some software that does that, which is why I asked for help finding such an app on Server Fault. " I need a software that can automatically generate a map of the network topology."

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it in a **very** long time but [What'sUpGold](http://www.whatsupgold.com/products/whatsup-gold-plugins/whatsconnected/index.aspx) used to ping everything on your network and generate a diagram.

Comment: If it is using icmp to ping everything, this would totally fail on most networks I work with as they don't respond to an icmp echo request :-)

Comment: It was a much different age. ;-)